# Why LEFT JOIN doesnt bring me all Month fields with NULL values

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have data only till April current month. So I am trying to use LEFT JOIN to bring the rest of the months till the end of the year by joining calendar table. . 
Calendar table has YearNumber, MonthNumber and MonthName.
What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT      
            Underwriter, 
            sum(case when TransactionType IN ('Policy', 'Reinstatement') then 1 ELSE 0 END) as PoliciesBound,               
            b.MonthNum,
            b.YearNum,
            b.MonthName

FROM        tblCalendar b  
LEFT JOIN   Test_Plaza_ProductionReport a ON b.MonthNum=Month(a.EffectiveDate)  AND b.YearNum = YEAR(a.EffectiveDate)
--FROM      Test_Plaza_ProductionReport
WHERE       Year(a.EffectiveDate)=2016 AND Underwriter <>'Batcheller, Jerry'
GROUP BY    Underwriter,
            b.YearNum,
            b.MonthName,
            b.MonthNum
```

Result should be like this:[image]

But my result only till April:
[image]

what am I missing by using LEFT JOIN?

Comment: You are negating your `outer join` with the `where` criteria.  Move that criteria to the `join` instead and it should work for you.

Comment: Move criteria to the join? What do you mean? Thanks

Comment: Tip: Use (more) meaningful aliases and apply them to all columns. It isn't clear where `Underwriter` and `TransactionType` come from. Using `... from tblCalendar as Cal left outer join Test_Plaza_ProductionReport as ProdRpt ...`. Even `C` and `PR` would be more useful than `a` and `b`.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the `where` criteria is negating your `outer join`.  Try this instead:

```
...
FROM tblCalendar b  
    LEFT JOIN Test_Plaza_ProductionReport a ON     
        b.MonthNum=Month(a.EffectiveDate) AND 
        b.YearNum = YEAR(a.EffectiveDate) AND 
        a.Underwriter <>'Batcheller, Jerry'
WHERE       b.YearNum=2016 
GROUP BY    Underwriter,
            b.YearNum,
            b.MonthName,
            b.MonthNum
```

Note, I'm assuming the `underwriter` field is in the report table and not the calendar table.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. Sorry for simple questions.